# Textarea keeps encoding double quotes, but where?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, encoding

What I know is: I have a text area that people can dump a description in (e.g. **This is a description with "double quotes"**). I then save that to a database, and in the database, it should not end up encoded, but it does (**This is a description with &quot;double quotes&quot;**)

- When I print the value gotten from the database, I get the encoded string (phpymadmin confirms that it's stored encoded, which it shouldn't be)
- When I print the value before submitting it to the database, I get the right, non encoded, string.
- I've tried `html_entity_decode` before saving it, but it still gets saved encoded.
- I'm certain there's no transformation, filter, etc. of the string happening by my code anywhere else.

Any idea?

edit: Nevermind, I had a function somewhere deep in the callstack that did a htmlspecialchars on the data. Stupid mistake, but if anything, this thread has been my rubber ducky.

Comment: Are you using a model, PDO, or mysql functions to run the query?

Comment: Providing your code might help..

Comment: `magic_quotes_gpc = Off` in your php.ini

Comment: @JoshuaBixler I am indeed using PDO. However I have many other forms that work just fine. This is the only one using a plain textarea. Normal inputs work just fine with quotes.